# Determing Height of DIV set in percentage, not pixels

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div set in pixels (divPix) and a div set in percentage (divPer). The height of divPer will vary with it's content. I want the browser to re-size the height of divPix to match the height of divPer. How would I go about that? Thank you.

Comment: It all depends on the structure. Are they nested? Are they side-by-side? An example would be helpful.

Comment: pls correct if wrong, after setting the height for the divPix, that element cannot grow or shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Probably could get away with a quick one off bit of jQuery to get it done.

HTML

```
<div id="divPix"></div>
<div id="divPer"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $('#divPix').height( $('#divPer').height() );
});
```

Comment: Only thing to add here is ensuring these elements have the same margin/padding/border set.